# FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken() is generating two different types of token

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using the code below to generate FCM Registration token for implementing device-to-device push notification service.

```
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

    // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
    saveRegistrationToLocalStorage(refreshedToken);
}
```

The code generates two different kinds of token. One with 152 characters and the other with 140 characters (Have tried more than 40-50 times, the generated token has either 140 or 152 characters). The tokens are used for device-to-device push notification using POST method.

Token with 140 characters - works with firebase console, but **not from device's POST method** to catch a push notification.

Token with 152 characters - works fine both with firebase console and device's POST method to catch a push notification.

**The questions are:**

1. Is a token with 140 character a normal one in FCM? Or is it unusual?
2. If it is a normal one, why it is unable to catch a push notification? (There is absolutely no problem with a token with 152 characters)
3. If 140 is a unusual size of a token, what I can do to produce a 152
   size in every installation?

You can have a look at the POST method I am using:

```
private class sendPushNotification extends AsyncTask<PushNotificationParams, Void, Void>  {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(PushNotificationParams... params) {
        String device_token = params[0].device_token;
        String notification_body = params[0].notification_body;
        String notification_title = params[0].notification_title;
        String authKey = "AIzaSy.......Xz4";   // FCM AUTH KEY
        String FCMurl = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

        try{
            URL url = new URL(FCMurl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization","key="+authKey);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");

            //custom data
            Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
            data.put("data_1",data_1);
            data.put("data_2", data_2);
            data.put("data_3", data_3);
            data.put("title", notifcation_title);   // Notification title
            data.put("body", notification_body); // Notification body
            JSONObject map_data = new JSONObject(data);
            //custom data ends here

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("to", device_token.trim());
            JSONObject info = new JSONObject();
            json.put("data", map_data); 

            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(json.toString());
            wr.flush();
            conn.getInputStream();

        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("Response","from http push", e);

        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to replicate this issue. I tried it many times and it always returns 152 characters. Is this behavior random or not? Is there a certain instance, that it only produces 140 tokens?

Comment: no. sometimes it produces 152 and sometimes 140 in the same device.

Comment: The issue is only occurring in one device? It is indeed a weird behavior if that's the case.

Comment: No, not is one specific device. It can occur in any device, but there's no guaranty in which number of installation it will happen.

Comment: @gerardnimo, Check my answer. If you have any suggestion, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per everyone's answer, I assumed that there might be some other service in my app that's causing the truncated token. The app was previously configured for **Parse Push Notification**. I removed everything that were associated with PPN, and seems like the problem is gone!

Answer (score 0):

This is an observation and question that is too long to post as a comment.

I tested on a single device and triggered fetch of a new token by clearing app data or calling `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId()`. The received token was always 152 characters.  I observed that the first 12 characters of the token are the 11 character instance ID returned by  `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getId()` followed by a ':' followed by a 140 character string.  For example:

```
Instance ID = dL1lPMbSutI (11 chars)
Token       = dL1lPMbSutI:APA91xLz52hcPbGg...hhHrh4h_xFr0318k (152 chars total)
```

When you get a 140 character token, does it have the 12 character prefix of Instance ID and colon?

Comment: You are exactly on right track mate! Yes, sometimes the first 11 characters+ ':' = total 12 characters are missing from the token. And it can happen in any device as far I have observed.

Comment: @SudipPodder: I tested with version 9.4.0 of the Firebase libs.  What version are you using?

Comment: Check my answer. If you have any suggestion, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but I can't replicate the issue on my end as well. Also, it's not advisable to store the Authorization key in the client app per Google's documentation about the [best practices for securely using API keys](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6310037?hl=en&ref_topic=6262490).

I'd suggest you to use an app server for device to device messaging, see the Firebase documentation for [sending upstream messages on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/upstream).

Comment: Check my answer. If you have any suggestion, please let me know.